# how to calculate 'better than X% of users' in a column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table just like this:

```
|   id  |   totalScore   |
--------------------------
|   1   |       -3       |
|   2   |        6       |
|   3   |       10       |
|   4   |        7       |
|   5   |       -4       |
|   6   |        4       |
|   7   |       -3       |
...
```

So for a given number (example 5), I want to find *** You're better than 10% of users! ***, or 20%, or 30%, etc.

How can I do this? Maybe using `average` of `totalScore` column and `group by` 10, 20, 30 values? Is it possible?

I'm using Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the score for the user (5 in your case)
2. Count all users where score is lower than 5
3. Divide that amount by the total amount of users and times a 100 for a percentage

E.g. you'll have a user with score 5.
You have a total of 7 users out of which 4 have a lower score than 5, resulting in
`4/7*100 = 57%`